# Averiguar tipo de una clase tipada para compararlo con objeto

Tags: c#

¿Cómo averiguo el tipo de una clase tipada para compararlo con un objeto?

Éste es mi código:

```
public static Salon<T> operator +(Salon<T> salon, T per)
{
    if (salon.Equals(per))
        throw new NoAgregaException("El elemento es del tipo " + per.GetType() + " y se esperaba  " + salon.GetType());

    if (salon._elementos.Count < salon._capacidad)
        throw new NoAgregaException("asdfadsf");
    else 
        salon._elementos.Add(per);

    return salon;
}
```

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta,pero puedes ser que te refieras a algo como `if (per Is Salon)` ...? Otra pregunta...si solo quieres "sumar" objetos de tipo `Salon`,por que pones el segundo parametro con un tipo genérico?

Comment: o sea si tengo una  clase tipada salon<T> como hago para saber que tipo es ? o que tipo entro ?